# Flutter HTTP GET request not working with body as a parameter

Tags: json, rest, http, flutter, dart

I have a REST API that takes in a `GET` request with a JSON body as:

```
{
    "cart_only_items": true
}
```

and the head as:

```
{
      "Authorization": "Token my_auth_token",
}
```

and returns a response as:

```
{
    "items": [...]
}
```

This REST API's `GET` request works just fine on postman.

So, I tried to implement this request in Flutter as follows:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

void getCart() async {
    Map<String, String> reqHead = {
      "Authorization": "Token my_auth_token",
    };
    Map<String, dynamic> reqBody = {"cart_only_items": true};
    String reqURL = "${my_base_url}details/";
    Response res = await get(
      reqURL,
      body: jsonEncode(reqBody),
      headers: reqHead,
    );
  }
```

But in the above code, I got a dart analysis error like:

```
error: The named parameter 'body' isn't defined. (undefined_named_parameter at [shoppingapp] lib/pages/Cart.dart:39)
```

So, what's the right way to make a `GET` request to a `REST API` that requires a JSON input using Flutter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because, *GET* request is not allowed to pass any kind of data in the body. To pass data you have to use *POST* request or query parameters in *GET* request.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void getCart() async {

Map data = {
  'key1': 1,
  'key2': "some text"
}

String body = json.encode(data);

http.Response response = await http.post(
  url: 'https://example.com',
  headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
  body: body,
);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
body: json.decode(reqBody.body),
```

instead of body: jsonEncode(reqBody) in your code.

Comment: Doesn't work. The error is that the named parameter `body` doesn't exit for the method `get`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you have no control over the API GET endpoints that require some data. Here's the hack:

Add the data as parameters to the URL.
For example:

```
String reqURL = "${my_base_url}details?user_id=${user.id}";
```

Comment: This is working for me. But why ?